Horizontal Line on LCD monitor that isn't dead or stuck, the pixels are taking on the values of pixels lower on the screen
My monitor has a horizontal line across the whole screen that displays the colors that should be slightly below it.
Since this is not a case of dead pixels, hot pixels, or stuck pixels, what would this be classified as and how would I go about fixing it? It is a Gigabyte M32U monitor with an IPS panel.
Here we can see the phenomenon happen. The line shows black except for when it is above the green image.

There is also a line of strictly green pixels running up the screen vertically. It is slightly to the left of the center of the screen. Both of these appeared at the same time.


Have you tested with another input source ? Its definitely not showing 'the colors below it', because the all white background should adopt the white color as well. It seems like its just light bleeding through.

I have tested another HDMI and in the monitors menus. In both cases the line still appears.

Looks like "cross-hairs" from some PC app, or a monitor setup app. Does it show when booting another OS from USB? Does it show at other resolutions and refresh rates?

It shows in the monitor settings and on different hdmi inputs. It is definitely not a windows issue. On other refresh rates/resolutions it remains.

Your monitor does have built in crosshair function (its a gaming monitor afterall). Since the damage seems to be right in the middle, it might still be due to that. You can shift the crosshair around with the monitor's menu settings. You could also see if you can try hooking it up with the displayport to rule out HDMI port damage. If it all fails its likely permanent damage to the monitor.

That is very likely a bad LCD or GPU
